# Getting this NotReadableError in mobile browsers when trying to read file using fileReader for uploading to s3

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, filereader

I am trying to upload files (in pdf, doc and docx formats), to s3 presigned url in React JS. I am using fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer and the mobile users are getting the following error on fileReader.onError:

NotReadableError: The requested file could not be read, typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference to a file was acquired.

This is working fine in desktop web but failing for a lot of users using android web and some failures in ios aswell.

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = (e) => {
  // uploading to s3
  uploadFileToS3(e.target.result);
};

fileReader.onerror = (err) => {
  console.error("Error in fileReader", fileReader.error);
};

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Does anyone know why this happens for some Android users and working fine in the web desktop?
 I tried to replicate this issue in a few Android devices but didn't face any issues. But our error logs show that a lot of Android users faced this issue.